# How to check if some words from several text files are written in Hindi, and what files are written in English?

Tags: python

I have several files written in Hindi or in English. I have to check which ones are written in English and which ones in Hindi. Cannot open one by one to check, because are more than 2.000 text files.

So, is it possible for Python to show me what are the files written in Hindi and what files are written in English?

I just want to know if it's possible and how to do it. I'll do the code if anyone gives me an idea of how this can be done.

For example, I was thinking of putting a few basic words in a dictionary, and making a function that if it finds 3 of such words, it means that the whole text is in English.

```
pattern = r'<h3\x20.*(\b(the|you|which|view|because|here|have)\b.*){5,}.*</h3>'
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: What kind of files? Are there non-language files? Are there binary files? Are there files containing neither English nor Hindi? Both English and Hindi?

Comment: simple text files, books, stories... plain words

Comment: You can use fasttext to perform language identification (langid) on a small sliver of these files (say, the first 1k characters) and check the returned language code. Perhaps an easier way would be to count the number of ASCII characters and the number of unicode characters (assuming the Hindi is written in Devanagari)...

Comment: Docs on fasttext language identification: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html Code example for language identification: https://medium.com/@c.chaitanya/language-identification-in-python-using-fasttext-60359dc30ed0

Comment: For example, I was thinking of putting a few basic words in a dictionary, and making a function that if it finds 3 of such words, it means that the whole text is in English. 

`pattern8 = r'<h3\x20.*(\b(the|you|which|view|because|here|have)\b.*){3,}.*</h3>'`

Comment: Hindi speakers will codeswitch often, so you're going to get a lot of false positives in general with a heuristic like a regex.